# Comando exec não funciona em python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Bem, não estou conseguindo executar funções externas (com exec) que alterarão listas globais para que seja usada em minha função principal, segue código:

```
m = []
n = []

def mp((a,b),p):
   c = [n[0] for n in p]
   d = [z.index for z in c if (a == z)]

   if len(d) == 1 and ((((sum(p) - p[d[0]]) + b) % 5) == 0 ):
           return m.append((((sum(p) - p[d[0]]) + b),d[0]))
   elif len(d) > 1 :
       return ( m.append((((sum(p) - p[d[i]]) + b),d[i])) for i in d if ((sum(p) - p[d[i]]) + b) % 5 == 0 ) 
   elif ( len(d) == 0 ):
       return m.append(None)

def mp2((a,b),p):
   c = [n[0] for n in p]
   e = [k.index for k in c if (b == z)]

   if len(e) == 1 and ((((sum(p) - p[e[0]]) + a) % 5) == 0 ):
       return  n.append((((sum(p) - p[e[0]]) + a),e[0]))
   elif len(e) > 1 :
       return ( n.append((((sum(p) - p[e[i]]) + a),e[i])) for i in e if ((sum(p) - p[e[i]]) + a) % 5 == 0 ) 
   elif ( len(e) == 0 ):
       return n.append(None)

def maior_ponto((a,b),p):
   g = mp((a,b),p)
   h = mp2((a,b),p)
   exec(g)
   exec(h)
   u = (m+n)
   return(r[1] for r in u if max(r[0]))
```

O erro retornado no terminal é:

```
python bloco313.py
  File "bloco313.py", line 71
    exec(g)
SyntaxError: unqualified exec is not allowed in function 'maior_ponto' it contains a nested function with free variables
```

Qual o problema na função? Não identifiquei problema de variáveis. Estou Usando python 2.7.5 no terminal do Ubuntu

Comment: Como você chama a funcao `maior_ponto`? A proposito, tente nomear melhor suas variaveis e funcoes com nomes autoexplicativos.

Answer (score 1):

No Python 2.x, a funcão exec não pode aparecer em funcoes que possuam "funcões" com variáveis livres. Uma expressão geradora implicitamente define um codigo objeto para o codigo que deve ser executado em cada iteracão dessa funcão. Na funcão `maior_ponto` você chama a "variavel livre" `max()` dentro da expressao geradora (`max` dentro do `return`, nesse caso), o que impede essa funcão de usar `exec`.

O seguinte codigo (sem `max`), por exemplo, funciona:

```
def maior_ponto((a,b),p):
   g = mp((a,b),p)
   h = mp2((a,b),p)
   exec(g)
   exec(h)
   u = (m+n)
   return(r[1] for r in u if r[0])
```

Em Python 3.x a funcão `exec` foi alterada e não deve mais apresentar esse tipo de erro.

Resposta retirada do StackOverflow em inglês: [Explicacão do comportamento de exec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9195309/any-explanation-of-execs-behavior)

Comment: oww, obrigado pela ajuda, realmente o erro foi esse... na verdade, sobre a questão da nomeação de função, é um trabalho acadêmico que estou realizando, com nomes de função pré-definidas. Como preciso executar mp e mp2 antes do return, o que devo fazer? mp e mp2 alteram variáveis globais que eu usarei no retorno, onde preciso retornar na geração de d-uplas, o elemento r[0] do máximo de r[1].

Comment: Não pode retornar todo o elemento u e fazer essa verificacão do valor r[1] fora da funcão? Não é a solucão ideal, mas deve funcionar. Ps: se a resposta está certa a aceite por favor!

Comment: @N4Dr seria legal você marcar e aceitar essa resposta.